Unable to gitignore .nx/cache from my Angular project after migrating NX
I am in the process of migrating Angular for a project I am working on. I need to migrate NX in the process. On one of the recent NX updates (I believe it was v16 -> v17), they added in .nx/cache, which is supposed to be added to the .gitignore file when nx is migrated.
I have tried an egregious amount of gitignore lines to attempt to see if my formatting was just wrong somewhere:
.nx\cache
.nx\cache\*
.nx/cache
.nx/cache/*
.nx/cache/file-map.json
ID_Client/.nx/cache
ID_Client/.nx/cache/*
ID_Client/.nx/cache/file-map.json
/.nx/cache
/.nx/cache/*
/.nx/cache/file-map.json
/ID_Client/.nx/cache
/ID_Client/.nx/cache/*
/ID_Client/.nx/cache/file-map.json
ID_Client\.nx\cache
ID_Client\.nx\cache\*
ID_Client\.nx\cache\file-map.json
\.nx\cache
\.nx\cache\*
\.nx\cache\file-map.json
\ID_Client\.nx\cache
\ID_Client\.nx\cache\*
\ID_Client\.nx\cache\file-map.json

Yet everytime I delete .nx\cache\file-map.json, it just keeps coming back.
I have tried git rm -r --cached .nx/cache/*, But the files just come right back.
A gif showing full repro of the problem: NX Git Ignore Issue

In our .gitignore, we have .nx/, so maybe it's because you don't have a trailing slash?

Since you are doing it in the editor, it could be an editor bug, try restarting the editor.

Trailing slash did not work unfortunately

I think I got it to work. I believe it probably was an editor bug / some other bug. I did git rm -r --cached .nx/cache/* and when I did this, I got a critical Git error that no file named file-map.json could be found, and after that it stopped returning. So one of the gitignore changes worked (still could be the trailing slash) AND there was likely an editor bug that caused it to look as if it hadn't worked.

Thanks to both of you for your quick responses!
